# The keyboard for the UITextField does not appear on first tap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, first-responder, uiresponder

I have created an action that changes the color of `UITextField`. But when I tap on the textfield it changes color but the keyboard does not appear. The keyboard appears only on second tap. Is this an issue of first responder? I'm new to `Swift` programming.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    textfield1.addTarget(
        self,
        action: #selector(textfield1.handleFrontTap(_:)),
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin
    )
}

func handleFrontTap(sender: UITextField) -> Void {
    print("tap working")
    setColor()
    self.textfield1.endEditing(true)

}
```

Comment: Don't you think it's your self.textfield1.endEditing(true) that's cancelling the keyboard showing?

Comment: Got it! That was stupid of me. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: I'll post this as answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you think it's your self.textfield1.endEditing(true) that's cancelling the keyboard showing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change control event from `EditingDidBegin` to `TouchUpInside`

And remove this line of code:

```
self.textfield1.endEditing(true)
```